# Exact field meaning of /proc/stat

Tags: proc

everyone

I need to know the exact meaning of every field in /proc/stat file. I read `man proc` and it only lists several common fields in various architecture and I find in Ubuntu, it includes several other fields in cpu row.

the below is output in my system and cpu rows contain up to 10 columns while the manual only gives 8 column definitions. Furthermore, I can't match the order of columns between my output and the manual.

```
cpu  606833 402 200307 3888129 69330 0 2702 0 18958 0
cpu0 305810 176 95771 1937157 42348 0 2581 0 9824 0
cpu1 301023 226 104535 1950972 26982 0 121 0 9134 0
intr 52047763 122 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1134857 0 0 444732 0 0 0 307878 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 52 8016227 602 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
ctxt 91496615
btime 1334106197
processes 27829
procs_running 1
procs_blocked 0
softirq 8764373 0 5353481 964 133618 444766 0 560785 671622 2332 1596805
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the Linux documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt):

- user: normal processes executing in user mode
- nice: niced processes executing in user mode
- system: processes executing in kernel mode
- idle: twiddling thumbs
- iowait: waiting for I/O to complete
- irq: servicing interrupts
- softirq: servicing softirqs
- steal: involuntary wait
- guest: running a normal guest
- guest_nice: running a niced guest